# Jquery to change form action and, Pass user id through action

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a modal where a user fill the data and when user press the submit button, a id fetch from jQuery and save data in datable according to the user id.
So, I have to fetch the id from jQuery and have to pass through PHP variable.

Here is my query for changing my form URL:

```js
$('#get_form').attr('action', '{{ url("admin/report/update/"."$id="obj.data('id'))" }}');
```

And, here is my form

```xml
<form action="" id = "get_form" method="post" class="ajax-form modal-content" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I am unable to set the URL perfectly.

Comment: "unable to" means what specifically? What error or unexpected result did you get? Please be specific and clear about the problem.

Comment: Why don't you do it on the direct `form` tag? And what is `obj.data('id')`?

Comment: the error appear $id not found. basically I can't did the correct concatenation @ADyson

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message? Don't abbreviate or paraphrase it. Add it to your question using the "edit" button, don't put it into the comments. And please show us where `$id` is defined, so we have got a [mre] of your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing blade with js. Try formatting the url like this:

```js
const url = "{{ url('admin/report/update/:id') }}".replace(':id', obj.data('id'))
// generates admin/report/update/1 assuming obj.data('id') is equal to 1

$('#get_form').attr('action', url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var id = $('some-id').val();  // a hidden value

 var url = "{{ url('admin/report/update/') }}" + id;

 $('#get_form').attr('action', url);
```